# JAXB customisation for a specifc class

Tags: wsdl, jaxb, xjc

Is it possible to apply a JAXB custom binding to one (or a set) of specific classes from the WSDL?

From what I gather, going through the globalBidings element applies the customisation to *all* classes generated from the WSDL. I would like to be able to name the classes to which the customisation is applied.

So rather than, say...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <globalBindings>
        <superClass name="com.syh.Shape"/>
    </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

... is there someway to limit the scope of the superclass?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `<bindings>` to customize a specific schema element (i.e. complex type). For your task I'd recommend using the [Inheritance plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin):

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='shape']">
        <inheritance:extends>com.syh.Shape</inheritance:extends>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```